RequireJS Error "No define call for core/first" on Moodle Installation via Docker
I'm working on a project that involves deploying Moodle using Docker. The setup includes two Docker containers: one for the database (MariaDB) and one for Moodle (i also have a container for django, but i don't think is relevant for this specific problem). I developed and tested the containers on my Mac and everything works as expected. However, when I shared the project with a friend using GitHub, and he tried to run it on his Windows laptop, he encountered JavaScript errors during the Moodle installation page that do not occur on my Mac. The main error, shown in the browser's console, are:
require.min.js:5 Uncaught Error: No define call for core/first
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine
    at makeError (require.min.js:5:1067)
    at Object.completeLoad (require.min.js:5:12223)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (require.min.js:5:13016)
makeError @ require.min.js:5
completeLoad @ require.min.js:5
onScriptLoad @ require.min.js:5
load (async)
req.load @ require.min.js:5
load @ require.min.js:5
load @ require.min.js:5
fetch @ require.min.js:5
check @ require.min.js:5
enable @ require.min.js:5
enable @ require.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:5
each @ require.min.js:5
enable @ require.min.js:5
init @ require.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ require.min.js:5
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.min.js:5
o @ require.min.js:5
requirejs @ require.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ editadvanced.php?id=2:2233

editadvanced.php?delayStartupUntil=configured:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at            editadvanced.php?delayStartupUntil=configured:1:1)

editadvanced.php?id=2:2710 Uncaught TypeError: M.form.shortforms is not a function
    at editadvanced.php?id=2:2710:51
    at YUI._notify (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.18.1/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:2:1727)
    at yui_combo.php?rollup/3.18.1/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:2:1198
    at YUI._notify (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.18.1/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:2:1727)
    at YUI.T (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.18.1/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:2:2653)
    at e.Loader._finish (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.18.1/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:9:5471)
    at e.Loader._onSuccess (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.18.1/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:9:5985)
    at e.Loader.p (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.18.1/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:10:1933)
    at e.Loader.onSuccess (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.18.1/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:10:2733)
    at s._finish (yui_combo.php?rollup/3.18.1/yui-moodlesimple-min.js:5:4335)

This error prevents JavaScript from running correctly on the installation page. Here are some additional details:
Docker Versions: We are both using the latest version of Docker.
Browsers: The error occurs on multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox) on his Windows laptop.
Configuration: The Moodle version we are deploying is Moodle 4.4, and our Docker setup includes custom .dockerignore and Dockerfile configurations, which I can share if needed.
I try changing the gitignore and dockerignore, but this did not solve the issue
this is the dockerignore:
# Ignore version control directories
.git/
.gitignore

# Ignore all bytecode compiled files
__pycache__/
*.pyc
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# Ignore Docker files that are not needed in the build context
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml

# Ignore virtual environment
venv/

# Ignore any other unnecessary files
*.log
tmp/
local_settings.py

# Distribution / packaging
build/
dist/
*.egg-info/
*.egg

# Development tools
.vscode/
.idea/

# OS generated files
.DS_Store

# Moodle data
moodledata/

